# Have TCP client search for TCP Server

Tags: c, node.js, tcp, ip, arduino

#### Background

I am using a SparkCore wireless arduino board to connect to a local Node.js server.  The server includes a local intranet TCP server that a TCP client programmed onto the SparkCore connects to.

#### Problem

If I run the server on a different network, the server has a different local IP address.  When I do this, I have to reprogram the SparkCore arduino to tell it the new local IP address of the server to connect its TCP client to.  This is not ideal for a variety of reasons.

#### Question

Is there a way to have the client dynamically search for the TCP server or alternatively have the server broadcast to TCP clients in a way that would inform the client of the local IP address to use for the server without initially hardcoding it?  I would love to do this in way that did not involve iterating through a bunch of IPs on a specific port to see if a connection is made.  That being said, if that's the only way to do this, then so be it.

Comment: You can have the server also listen for UDP broadcasts on a port. Then send a reply to the source address when a broadcast arrives. The client then just sends a broadcast, and wait a while for a reply.

Comment: @perh Would this work because UDP does not target a specific IP?  If so, this would work well and I can mark it as correct if you put it in an answer.

Comment: It works because UDP has the _option_ to not target a specific IP. You can send a packet to the broadcast address (or local multicast group, in the case of ipv6), all computers on the local network will then see the packet.  (If you run ifconfig this would be the address in 'bcast' or 'broadcast' for ipv4, it is both easier and more complex for ipv6)

Comment: Altough i think too UDP is the solution, be aware of the downsides of broadcasting and UDP in general. "Broad"-casting will not work that way in IPv6, so a migration will break the system (multicast works). And data sent on UDP is not reliable; it could be received multiple times or not at all, and/or in different order. So, after you found the server, switch to TCP again and be prepared that you could get no reponse from the server until you tried 2-3 searches (or more).

Comment: @perh And it would be the broadcast address from the server, yes?

Comment: also bradcast and multicast message will be blocked outside your LAN(even inside, if router/firewall/whatever is set to block them)

Comment: @mbeasley The client would send the packet to the local network broadcast address. The server would listen to the udp port on the ANY address (*, ::, 0 or ANY or whatever it is in your API/language of choice). When it detects a packet it would send a reply to the source (which will be the client IP#). The client can then use the source address of that packet as the packet (conveniently enough this is already available when received using recvfrom). UDP is not reliable, as has been stated, but it is reliable enough. Just have the client repeat the request if it does not get a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the arduino booting? If it's booting using DHCP, one method would be to provide a customer DHCP option that provided the address of the node.js server. `ntp`, for instance, can configure itself in a similar way. This has the advantage that the arduino need not be on the same local subnet as the node.js server.

An alternative (slightly disgusting) would be to use an A record within your domain (let's say `nodejs.example.com`. Configure the local DNS recursive server to explicitly return this value (I am presuming you might have lots of different deployments with lots of different `nodejs` servers).

A third possibility would be to send out some form of discovery packet, either by broadcast, or better by multicast UDP. Assuming it's on the same LAN, the `nodejs` server could then reply. Clearly you might need to concern yourself with a rogue server impersonating your `nodejs` server, and therefore might need to add some security (e.g. use a shared secret, send a random nonce plus the nonce hashed with the shared secret to the server, the server checks the hash, and replies with the answer, the nonce, plus the answer hashed with the shared secret and the nonce, each of which the client then checks).

Comment: Could I reverse the UDP option by having the server broadcast a UDP discovery packet (on loop) and the client listen for it?  This is for development and testing, so security is not a concern at this point.